# Mocking static method for java Spring Integration test

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, powermock

I have the following code and I want to mock the `Util` class method to return file path of my testing directory, and I want to read files from there for my integration testing. Base class takes care of the Spring bean configuration.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Util.class)
public class CalculatorControllerIT extends BaseIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    CalculatorController calculatorController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockStatic(Util.class);
        when(Util.getDataDirectory()).thenReturn("./");
    }
}
```

Static method

```
when(Util.getDataDirectory()).thenReturn("./");
```

is not working and I am not able to mock it. How can I get around with it so that my integration test on `calculatorController` works fine?

Comment: What does "is not working" exactly mean? What errors do you get? I use the same methods like you and for me that works perfectly (even with static final methods).

Comment: If at all possible, make your `Util` non-static and pass it in as a constructor parameter.

Comment: Is the path returned by `Util.getDataDirectory()` a hardcoded constant in Java code? If so, I would say the method is badly implemented, since such paths usually vary depending on the execution environment and it therefore should be a *configurable* parameter. And if it is configurable, then it should be possible to configure it properly for the test environment, without any mocking.